# Summary of a single stock on Robinhood

Tags: robinhood

Is there a way to see the total month end or up to now summary of trades for a single stock I have performed on Robinhood? To not see individual trades, but sum of all trades for a single stock. Meaning something like: AAPL *Total* Buy= $1000 *Total* Sell = $1050.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively in Robinhood. Robinhood issues a monthly statement that has all the information you would need but does not give you flexibility to see what you're after. So you'd need to develop an approach to parse this information from the statement or perhaps from the emails they send for each trade.

They do have a private API that people have used to automate trading which might be helpful to you but my research suggests it's not officially supported and there may be some TOS issues with using it for automation purposes.

Other platforms offer more robust reporting for sure.

Comment: Their monthly statement does not offer a summary of the form I want in my question. Or, did I not see the monthly statement right?

Comment: The monthly statement has the information you'd need to get what you want, but you'd have to parse it out to group by symbol.

Comment: exactly my question if there is an automated way to do that instead of counting hundreds of trades.

Comment: Edited to clarify, there may be tools you can use to get what you're after but the better idea is just to move to a better platform.

Comment: A broker with better reporting will segregate the trades by ticker  in the monthly and annual reports.  Obviously this would not help you mid month but it doesn't take a  huge amount  of effort to cut and paste and add the trades from the daily statements into Excel and sort by symbol.

Answer (score 0):

My broker's daily statements offer a Month and Year-To-Date  Performance summary.  I don't know what Robinhood offers in the way of statements but check there.